# Operations that can be performed in NBG

Tags: set-theory, axioms

The following is a set-theoretic issue that I have met in category theory.
Suppose you have a class $C$ and, for every element $c \in C$, a set $A_c$. Is it well defined the union $\bigcup_{c \in C} A_c$ of sets ranging over a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The union is simply $\{x\mid\exists c\in C: x\in A_c\}$, this is a form of predicative comprehension which is included in/provable from $\sf NBG$.

Another way of seeing this more clearly is to consider the case in $\sf ZF$, where you have a formula $\varphi_C(x)$ defining $C$, and a formula $\varphi_A(x,y)$ which defines the assignment of $A_c$ to each $c$ satisfying $\varphi_C(c)$. Then the union is given by the formula $\psi(x)$: $$\exists c\exists A(\varphi(c)\land\varphi_A(c,A)\land x\in A).$$

Comment: Yuppii!! One thing that it is not clear to me: to use comprehension, don't you have to place yourself in a class before?

I would like to ask you another class-related problem. If S is a set and C a class, is C^S (functions from S to C) a class? I know that the answer is "yes" for finite $S$ but i wonder if this generalizes.

Comment: No, in NBG you have a class-comprehension. Because the class of all sets is a class, you can always assume you carve out of that, so it doesn't matter anymore. To your other question, of course the answer is yes, again by the same idea, you can recognize the domain (it is the parameter $S$ here) and the range is a subset of $C$.

Comment: What about P(C) (subsets of C)? I know this is not a class, otherwise you have a paradox on the universe. But I could argue that P(C) = {A | forall x in A, x in C}. What's wrong with that? I mean, I don't understand the crucial point. Again, i don't see the use of the hypothesis that A_c is a set in your answer: is it true even if they are classes?

Comment: It is a class, since it only takes the *subsets* of $C$, and not the subclasses.

Comment: Aaaah. Well. You are right

Comment: That has been known to happen on occasion. :)

Comment: Thank you for your patience. You would deserve more than one thumb up! If you have a reference on these kind of subtleties, I would be grateful to you!

Comment: Well, I don't know any book that focuses on class-based set theories, and specifically NBG. It's really just carefully looking at what you're given. There's hardly any difficult and tricky deductions here...